# PHPStorm php-code indentation

Tags: phpstorm

I need these chunks of code to be indented properly like this:

```
$this->render('rights', array(
    'admin' => $admin,
    'editor' => $editor,
    'author' => $author,
));
```

and widget snippet:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'items' => array(
        array('label' => 'label', 'url' => 'url')
    )
)); ?>
```

With default PHPStorm settings it indents this code like this:

```
$this->render('rights', array(
                             'admin' => $admin,
                             'editor' => $editor,
                             'author' => $author,
                        ));
```

I went to Settings->Code Style->Wrapping and Braces and changed following options:

- Array initializer -> Align when multiple (uncheck)
- Method call arguments -> Align when multiple (uncheck)

The result is:

```
$this->render('rights', array(
        'admin' => $admin,
        'editor' => $editor,
        'author' => $author,
    ));
```

Still not the style I want, but that's all I managed to accomplish. Can you please point me to the option I need to change?

Answer (score 26):

Try selecting all the code and clicking :
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
It's auto indentation shortcut ...

Comment: New shortcut is Ctrl + Alt + L, which is great for mint users

Comment: That did the trick for phpstorm 2016.1 on Windows ☺ How would that be on MacOS?

Comment: On MAC it is simply `cmd + alt + L`

Comment: @avn most comfortable

Answer (score 7):

It seems a to be a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-6328). Please watch/vote or add your comments there.

Comment: 2016 and I still have this issue 

Answer (score 3):

I think this will help you in formatting
Your code
https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/8

Comment: Awesome link :)

Answer (score 2):

I've found that unchecking the following option solves the issue for me:

> Preferences > Editor > Code Style > PHP > Tab 'Wrapping and Braces' > Function/constructor call arguments > **Align when multiline**

This changes the following code:

```php
var $numbers = $this->thing(array(
                                "one",
                                "two",
                                "three",
                                "four",
                                "five",
                                "six"
                            ));
```

To be formatted like:

```php
var $numbers = $this->thing(array(
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six"
));
```